# How should i convert this string into dict in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there any way to convert this string into list of item???

```
'variants': ['{{attribute: 3, value: Red}, {attribute: 4, value: Yellow}}']
```

Comment: can you add your current code?

Comment: this is the data from json, so i should convert this into dict so that i can continue further

Comment: I suggest you to use `re` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_list = "'variants': ['{{attribute: 3, value: Red}, {attribute: 4, value: Yellow}, {attribute: 5, value: Green}}','{{attribute: 6, value: Red0}, {attribute: 7, value: Yellow0}, {attribute: 8, value: Green0}}']"

l= str_list.split("'variants':")[1][2:-1].split(",")
c=0
lst=[]
for s in l:
    kv=s.split(':')[1].strip("}'").strip()
    if(c%2==0):
        key=kv
    else:
        val=kv
        lst.append({'attribute':int(key),'value':val})
    c+=1
        
print(lst)
```

check whether this is what you want. Results are as follows:

```
[{'attribute': 3, 'value': 'Red'}, {'attribute': 4, 'value': 'Yellow'}, {'attribute': 5, 'value': 'Green'}]
```

Comment: No, i don't want output like that, i want {"attribute": 3, "value": "Red"}, {"attribute": 4, "value": "Yellow"} instead. And there will be a lot of data like this not only 2.

Comment: In that case I updated the post. check whether now you get the expected results